# Arrange multiple plots per page, but # of plots is not multiple of # of pages

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra, ggpubr, patchwork

I have used `wrap_plots()`, `ggarrange()`, or `grid.arrange()` in the past. However, I have not found how to arrange several plots per page, using a `for` loop, when the number of plots is not a multiple number of the number of pages wanted.

Let us say I have six plot and I want four plots per page, for  (quite a silly) instance. If I do the following, I get an error, obviously enough:

```
for (i in seq(1,6,4)) 
grid.arrange(plots[[i]] , plots[[i+1]] , plots[[i+2]] , plots[[i+3]], col = 2, row = 2)
```

I know I could create a loop up to the maximal multiple value of four in the list, and the create a second loop with the remaining plots, but I wonder if there is an easier and/or more elegant way to handle this.

Finally, using `wrap_plots()`or `ggarrange()` seems more complicated when I want to create multiple pages one after the other, even if they are complete 2*2: I do not get a viable pdf. I think I am missing something regarding those two.

Thanks you for your help.

Best,

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to create an index vector which assigns plots to pages. Afterwards you can loop over the pages like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(patchwork)

plots <- lapply(1:6, function(x) {
  ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg)) +
    geom_point() +
    labs(title = x)
})

pages <- (seq_along(plots) - 1) %/% 4

lapply(unique(pages), function(page) {
  wrap_plots(plots[pages %in% page])
})
#> [[1]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[2]]
```

[image]

Or using `ggarrange`:

```r
lapply(unique(pages), function(page) {
  ggarrange(plotlist = plots[pages %in% page])
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Stefan. Yeah, that solves part of the issue. However, there is still the issu with the plots on the last page being bigger than those in 2*2 pages. I guess I way round it would be just creating dummy plots for those slots beyond the last real plot, until a multiple of four is reached.